# type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart, oop

I'm building this app and I wanted to display a ListView of Images of actors and their names. So I made a Movieclass that takes the title of the movie (string), the bannerpath (string), the description (string), the id (int - used for hero animation) and the cast, which is a map. This map has contains the path to the picture and the name of the actor. Now I wanted to use this in my widget but after trying to do so I go the arrow above. This is the code of the model:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<MovieModel> get models =>
    movies.map((movie) => MovieModel.fromJson(movie)).toList();

List<Widget> get widgets =>
    models.map((model) => MovieWidget(model: model)).toList();

class MovieModel {
  MovieModel({
    required this.title,
    required this.cast,
    required this.bannerPath,
    required this.description,
    required this.id,
  });

  factory MovieModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MovieModel(
      title: json['title'],
      cast: json['cast'],
      bannerPath: json['bannerPath'],
      description: json['description'],
      id: json['id'],
    );
  }

  String title;
  String bannerPath;
  String description;
  List<Map> cast;
  int id;
}
```

and this is the movies variable I declared with all the info I want displayed in the app...

```
var movies = [
  {
    'title': '21',
    'bannerPath': 'assets/images/21_movie.jpeg',
    'id': 1,
    'description':
        '"21" is the fact-based story about six MIT students who were trained to become experts in card counting and subsequently took Vegas casinos for millions in winnings.',
    'cast': [
      {
        'name': 'Kate Bosworth',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Jim Slurgess',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Kevin Spacey',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'title': 'Endless Love',
    'bannerPath': 'assets/images/endless_love_movie.jpeg',
    'id': 2,
    'description':
        'The story of a privileged girl and a charismatic boy whose instant desire sparks a love affair made only more reckless by parents trying to keep them apart',
    'cast': [
      {
        'name': 'Alex Pettyfer',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Garbielle Wilde',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'bruce Greenwood',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'title': 'Kevin allein zuhaus',
    'bannerPath': 'assets/images/kevin_allein_zuhaus_movie.jpeg',
    'id': 3,
    'description':
        'Dieses Jahr fliegt die gesamte McAllister-Familie nach Frankreich, um dort gemeinsam Weihnachten zu feiern. Leider haben sie bei ihrer hektischen Abreise ihren achtjährigen Sprößling Kevin zu Hause vergessen. Dieser genießt natürlich seine neugewonnene Freiheit.',
    'cast': [
      {
        'name': 'Macaula Culkin',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Joe Pesci',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'John Heard',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'title': 'Little Woman',
    'bannerPath': 'assets/images/little_woman_movie.jpeg',
    'id': 4,
    'description':
        'rThe story follows the lives of the four March sisters—Meg, Jo, Beth, and Amy—and details their passage from childhood to womanhood. Loosely based on the lives of the author and her three sisters, it is classified as an autobiographical or semi-autobiographical novel.',
    'cast': [
      {
        'name': 'Saorse ROnan',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Timothée Chalmet',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Florence Pugh',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'title': 'Liebe braucht keine Ferien',
    'bannerPath': 'assets/images/love_movie.jpeg',
    'id': 5,
    'description':
        'Amanda ist enttäuscht von der Liebe und will nichts wie weg aus Los Angeles. Genauso geht es Iris in England. Über das Internet vereinbaren die beiden Frauen einen Häusertausch. In England trifft Amanda schon bald auf Iris attraktiven Bruder, und Iris lernt einen Arbeitskollegen von Amanda kennen.',
    'cast': [
      {
        'name': 'Jude Law',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Cameron Diaz',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Kate Winslet',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'title': 'Marvel Movies',
    'bannerPath': 'assets/images/marvel_movie.jpeg',
    'id': 6,
    'description':
        'The Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU) is an American media franchise and shared universe centered on a series of superhero films produced by Marvel Studios.',
    'cast': [
      {
        'name': 'Chris Evans',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Robert Downey Jr.',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Chris Hemsworth',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Scarlett Johansson',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'title': 'Oceans 12',
    'bannerPath': 'assets/images/oceans_12_movie.jpeg',
    'id': 7,
    'description':
        'Set three years after "Ocean\'s 11," this sequel shows us Danny Ocean gathering up his complete gang of con artists and thieves from the first film in New York City before they all jet off to Amsterdam, Rome, and Paris to pull off three seperate heists.',
    'cast': [
      {
        'name': 'Geroge Cloney',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Julia Roberts',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Catherine Zeta-James',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Brad Pitt',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'title': 'A star is born',
    'bannerPath': 'assets/images/star_movie.jpeg',
    'id': 8,
    'description':
        'Der in die Jahre gekommene Rockstar Jackson Maine entdeckt die talentierte Sängerin Ally und verliebt sich in sie. Ally hätte ihren großen Traum von einer Musikkarriere fast aufgegeben. Jackson fördert sie und nimmt sie schließlich sogar mit auf seine Tournee.',
    'cast': [
      'Lady Gaga',
      'Bradley Cooper',
      'Sam Elliot',
    ]
  },
  {
    'title': 'Frühstück bei Tiffany',
    'bannerPath': 'assets/images/tiffany_movie.jpeg',
    'id': 10,
    'description':
        'Holly Golightly sucht einen reichen Ehemann, hat gutbetuchte Freunde, eine namenlose Katze und einen mittellosen Begleiter, der ihr immer aus der Patsche hilft. Ihr Traum: eine Wohnung so schön wie bei Tiffanys. Doch dann fordert der Exmann alte Rechte ein, die Polizei stellt unbequeme Fragen, und der Heiratskandidat aus Brasilien verrschwindet.',
    'cast': [
      {
        'name': 'Audrey Hepburn',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'George Peppard',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Patricia Neal',
        'image': 'assets/images/actors/kate-bosworth--6282909-.jpg'
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I looked for a solution but so far I wasn't able to find one... Im just starting out with flutter and right now Im pretty much out of options, thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: The cast for "A star is born" is in a different format than the rest of the movies.

Comment: Ok so this I didn't see... I dont get the error anymore, but when I try to access the detail screen I get this error thrown + a screen freeze:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13z7y4GGh5SUWf4D4mihq9D_13RNHKM6p/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't have an answer off the top of my head, but this is an entirely different issue altogether. Maybe consider making another post with details about this new issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's only a type problem. If you declare movies like this: `List<Map<String, dynamic>> movies`, and create the classes like this: `List<MovieModel> mov = movies.map((e) => MovieModel.fromJson(e)).toList(); }` it should work.